# Axios promise value render always 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs, axios, undefined

Inside a `componentDiMount` function of a child component, I'm using an external function (`getResults`) to populate a state value. This `getResults` function, call an external API with axios.

Here is my code:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const cluster = '...';
    const index= '...'; 
    const field= '...';     
    const paragraphs = uuids.map(uuid => {
      // Get the results.
      getResults(cluster, index, field, uuid, 'source')
        .then(results => {
        // Get value with console.log OK.
        console.log(results);
        // Return a undefined value... 
        return results;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
    });
```

After reading many, many posts I see that my problem seems to be the axios delay to generate the results. To resolve my problem, I have tested many solutions without success: check the rendered value in the render section...

How can I resolve this problem? Do I modify an element in the `componentDiMount` function or directly in the external `getResults` function ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This assumes uuids has something in it - if you console.log() it out before the map, what does it show?

Comment: Yes, the const uuids is an array with several values. I'm creating the const 'paragraphs' to pass the array in the state.data. Maybe i should modify the code to include the setState inside the map function...

Answer (score 1):

Normally, in an axios request, the data comes in `results.data`

Also, because you don't return anything inside `.map`, it will just be an array of `undefined`.

You need to return inside `.map`

```
componentDidMount() {
    const cluster = '...';
    const index= '...'; 
    const field= '...';     
    const paragraphs = uuids.map(uuid => {
      // Get the results.
      // ADDED RETURN INSIDE .map
      return getResults(cluster, index, field, uuid, 'source')
        .then(results => {
        // Get value with console.log OK.
        console.log(results);
        // Return a undefined value... 
        return results;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  });
```

And if you want to get the data from `paragraphs`, you need to use `Promise.all` or `async`/`await` for it to work.